# How do you make an alert with rounded corners using Anko without using XML?

Tags: android, kotlin, anko

I'd like to make an alert with rounded corners using anko, without using any XML. I've pasted my current attempt below. Is there any way to make the alert's custom view completely transparent, or to make it rounded and change its background color?

[image: White corners]

```
class TestActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        alert {
            customView {
                verticalLayout {
                    backgroundDrawable = GradientDrawable().apply {
                        shape = GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE
                        cornerRadius = 15f
                        setColor(Color.BLACK)
                    }
                    for(i in 0..5){
                        textView("Hello World") {
                            textColor = Color.WHITE
                            gravity = Gravity.CENTER
                        }.lparams(matchParent,dip(50))
                    }
                }
            }
        }.show()
    }

}
```

Dependencies

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.21'
ext.anko_version='0.10.8'

implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha03'
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0-alpha05'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.2-alpha02'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0-alpha02'

// Anko Commons
implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-commons:$anko_version"

// Anko Layouts
implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-sdk15:$anko_version"
// sdk15, sdk19, sdk21, sdk23 are also available
implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-appcompat-v7:$anko_version"
```

Edit:

```
    var alertDialog: Dialog? = null
    alertDialog = alert {
        customView {
            verticalLayout {
                backgroundDrawable = GradientDrawable().apply {
                    shape = GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE
                    cornerRadius = 15f
                    setColor(Color.BLACK)
                }
                for(i in 0..5){
                    textView("Hello World") {
                        textColor = Color.WHITE
                        gravity = Gravity.CENTER
                    }.lparams(matchParent,dip(50))
                }
                button {
                    text = "Cancel"
                    setOnClickListener {
                        alertDialog?.dismiss()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }.show() as? Dialog

    // This right here does the trick
    alertDialog?.window?.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))
    alertDialog?.show()
```

does what I want. Thanks, blastervla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
val alertDialog: Dialog = alert {
    customView {
        /* Your custom view DSL */
    }
}.build() as Dialog // You can use conditional as? syntax for extra safety

// This right here does the trick
alertDialog.window?.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))
alertDialog.show()
```

Note that by doing this, you'll need to set titles and buttons by yourself inside the contentView, as they'll appear over the transparent background otherwise. If you need a dismiss button, you can do the following change in the dialog declaration:

```
var alertDialog: Dialog? = null
alertDialog = alert { 
    customView {
        /* ... */ 
        button {
            text = "Cancel"
            setOnClickListener {
                alertDialog?.dismiss()
            }
        }
    }
}.build()
/* ... */
```